# How can i make two redirects after a user logs in a page using Spring MVC in liferay portlets

Tags: jquery, html, http, spring-mvc, liferay-6

My question is very strange and i'm not entirely sure if it can be done. I am using Spring MVC in for Liferay and i am trying to achieve the following.
The application i am doing has two domain two portals which will be on two different urls. I need after the user logs in on the first portal, and his credentials are validated, To redirect him to a certain page with in the same portal and open the landing page of the other portal in a new tab.

I was trying to achive this on the following way. Since i can not have two response to a single log in function i tried, once he is loged in to rederect him using the liferay hook function After login redirect action.

Which takes me to the landing page of the first portal. In the same redirect action i create a cookie that notifies me that the user has been loged in here.

```
@Override
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {

    try {
        Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("loged_in_confirmed","1");
        response.addCookie(loginCookie);

        response.sendRedirect("somePage");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO
    }
```

On the page that the redirect is taking me to i have a jQuery document ready function that checks for the cookie. If the cookie is there it deletes it and it should rederect me to the other portal in a new tab.

However the opening of the new tab is always blocked by a pop up blocker. I've tried opening it with window.href, window.open with target blank, i even tried adding a hidden  link with `target ="_blank"` but still the pop up blocker gets him. I'm open to any sugestion, am i missing something in the way i am doing it or maybe i'm totally of target here and there is a totally different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers look to see whether the window is opening as a result of a user action. Essentially this means that window.open and other window openers will look at the call stack to see if you're handling an input event, and only allow the popup if you are. This brings to mind two options for opening the second page in a way that's compatible with popup blockers:

1. Open the popup when the user clicks login to a page that will log in separately to the second site or poll the already-in-process login, and then close itself if the login fails. Probably the nicest way to do this would be to set the popup to load a page that waits for the  login to succeed or fail and then returns either a redirect to the second portal or a snippet of JS that closes the popup.
2. Put a "click here to use the second portal" link on the first portal with target="_blank". This is what I would do unless loading both sites without user intervention was a client requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a clients requirement and that is why i was asking. Both of your suggestiveness were taken in consideration about two weeks ago and the client refused them. I think they've seen something similar like this on the web but i wasn't able to find a site that does this automatically. My other question is because i don't have the greatest experience with this things. Is this possible to be done with out any client interaction?